# Как освободить место после баннера

Tags: android

В разметке layout стоит вверху баннер на 50 пикселей по вертикали. Как автоматически освободить это место для других вьюшек(textView), какой командой, когда баннер не отображается? я видел в некоторых приложениях это работает (когда появляется баннер - он автоматически смещает вьюшки вниз). Я пытался делать по id невидимым(adView.destroy()), но пространство остается занятым

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того чтобы скрыть `View` и освободить место в `layout` нужно для него установить атрибут `View.GONE`:

```
View.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: Спасибо!!! работает, я как раз  пытался этой командой, только не знал что писать в скобках.